# Make object of a subclass from the super class

Tags: java, oop

Firstly, sorry for the poor English, it is not my first language

How would one go about creating a object of a type from a subclass via the super class. 
e.g. 
if I have a super class:

```
public class superClassName(){
    method(){
    make object of subclass type used
    }
```

and then I call the method in a subclass.

I'd like to have a an object created based on the subclass that's been called if that makes sense?

Comment: In what kind of scenario do you need that behavior?

Comment: I need to create a list of object but the code for each other subclass is the same, so I am trying to abstract the method further

Comment: @InsertRealName So what is stopping you in doing so? I mean this can be done. I am unable to see where are you stuck?

Comment: So it would be an instance of subclass creating other subclass instances (in a superclass method...)?

Comment: yeah, I am unable to get it to identify the subclass types @ernest_k

Comment: Object of type??

Answer (score 0):

Using reflection may provide the quickest solution (`this.getClass()` returns the concrete subclass):

```
void method(){
    //use default, no-arg constructor
    superClassName newObject = this.getClass().getConstructor().newInstance();
}
```

Alternatively, your parent class can declare an abstract method that forces subclasses to provide a supplier:

```
public abstract class superClassName(){
    abstract Supplier<superClassName> getInstanceSupplier();

    void method(){
        superClassName newObject = this.getInstanceSupplier().get();
    }
}
```

And implement it as simply as:

```
public class SubClassName extends superClassName {
    abstract Supplier<superClassName> getInstanceSupplier() {
        return () -> new SubClassName();
    }
}
```

Comment: He wants to instantiate sub classes from his super class which is not possible... Not my downvote btw